# RAM memory needed?

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

For Magento 2.3 and Elasticsearch 5.2, my system is an Ubuntu 18/04 with 2GB of RAM, is this RAM enough? (I have 6000 products more or less)

Comment: Is elasticsearch going to run on the same machine? Or on a separate one with 2gb?

Comment: In the same machine I'm going Magento, MySQL and Elasticsearch. My server is a digital ocean droplet with these features: 2GB / 2vCPUs / 60GB, I can switch to the service of 4GB / 2vCPUs / 60GB. Would this be enough?

Comment: Can't say for Magento/MySQL. But if you can start elasticsearch with 1gb HEAP, 9000 products will definitely fit. I can index and search for 1m documents in a 1gb instance. But note that I'm the only user though.

Comment: Only user on the server or in magento?

Comment: Only user that was running queries against elasticsearch. So I meant only one search request at a time. That can work for more but did not test it. Note that you can test for free for 14 days on cloud.elastic.co without a credit card. I think you can test a 1gb instance.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with Elasticsearch, it's my first time, and as I understand it, I configure this engine in magento and I do not have to do it and no more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89671/discussion-between-dadoonet-and-despotars).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento lists 2GB RAM as the minimum requirement: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

The problem ist that you should also set a minimum `memory_limit` of 512MB in your php.ini. This would mean that if you only 2GB RAM, you might run into memory issues.
Is the MySQL database also running on the same server? Because then it's not enough at all.

I would only run Magento 2 on a server that has at least 16GB of RAM. The actual usage does not only depend on your catalog size, but also how many websites/stores you have, how many visitors to your website etc.

Comment: My server is a digital ocean droplet with these features: 2GB / 2vCPUs / 60GB, I can switch to the service of 4GB / 2vCPUs / 60GB. Would this be enough? And yes, my database is hosted on the same server

Comment: Of course you can develop on this server, but I wouldn't use it for production. I told you what I would use in my answer. The performance just tends to get really bad. Of course, it depends on the individual shop, and you should test it.

Comment: Ok! Thank you for your answer. One question, for 2GB RAM, I have edited /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini and /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini with the following configuration: memory_limit = 2G max_execution_time = 1800 zlib.output_compression = On. And also the file /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options with this data: -Xms1g -Xmx1g. This would be the correct configuration?

Comment: This theoretically means that your software is allowed to use more RAM than the server has. Doesn't mean that this will occur. Also, don't forget that you also have the database, the Apache etc. As I said, should be ok for development, and not ok for production :)

Answer (score 2):

One will need up to 2GB RAM to update Magento. Create a swap file if you use a system with less than 2 GB of RAM to avoid failure in the update process.

Comment: My system have 8GB, I need create a swap too? or it is not necessary?